# WPF: How to merge windows across processes

Tags: c#, wpf, hwnd

I'm currently working on a feature in my WPF app, which allows the user to launch an external program. But I've got a problem.

```
// Here's a C# method, which handling the "open notepad" button click event
void OpenNotepad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();
}
```

By default, the Windows' taskbar handles *"my WPF application window"* and the *"Notepad window"* like this
[image]
But I would like to **merge these two windows** *(maybe this is not the most accurate expression)*, but how can I improve my code?
[image]\

*Any help is appreciated.*